# An error while using tune for hyper-parameters a deep learning model

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, hyperparameters

I'm trying to use `tune` to tune my model in Pytorch (https://docs.ray.io/en/latest/tune.html), as a starting point; I just tried to run their small example:

```
import torch.optim as optim
from ray import tune
from ray.tune.examples.mnist_pytorch import get_data_loaders, ConvNet, train, test


def train_mnist(config):
    train_loader, test_loader = get_data_loaders()
    model = ConvNet()
    optimizer = optim.SGD(model.parameters(), lr=config["lr"])
    for i in range(10):
        train(model, optimizer, train_loader)
        acc = test(model, test_loader)
        tune.track.log(mean_accuracy=acc)


analysis = tune.run(
    train_mnist, config={"lr": tune.grid_search([0.001, 0.01, 0.1])})

print("Best config: ", analysis.get_best_config(metric="mean_accuracy"))

# Get a dataframe for analyzing trial results.
df = analysis.dataframe()
```

And I got this error:

[image]

[image]

I run it on a remote machine requesting 100 GB of memory. Any help with that please?

Comment: Gosh that looks terrible. What version of Ray are you on?

Comment: I assume it's the latest one, because I install it as in the documentation: pip install 'ray[tune]' torch torchvision @richliaw

Comment: Can you try installing the nightly wheels? https://docs.ray.io/en/latest/installation.html