# How to find the optimal learning rate, number of epochs & decay strategy in Torch.optim.adam?

Tags: machine-learning, pytorch

I am working on a model trained on the MNIST dataset. I am using the torch.optim.adam model and have been experimenting with tuning the hyper parameters. After running a lot of tests, I have come to find a combination of hyper parameters that give 90% accuracy. However, I feel like maybe since I am new to this, there might be a more efficient way to find the optimal values of the hyperparameters. The brute force approach seems to depend on trial and error & I was wondering if there is certain strategy to find these values.
Example of the code being used is:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    end = time.time()
    model_ft = Net().to(device) 
    print(model_ft.network)
    criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss() 

    optimizer_ft = optim.Adam(model_ft.parameters(), lr=1e-3)

    exp_lr_scheduler = lr_scheduler.StepLR(optimizer_ft, step_size=9, gamma=0.5) 
    
    history, accuracy = train_test(model_ft, criterion, optimizer_ft, exp_lr_scheduler,
               num_epochs=15)
```

Here I would like to find the optimal values of:-

1. Learning Rate
2. Step Size
3. Gamma
4. Number of Epochs

   Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44260217/hyperparameter-optimization-for-pytorch-model

Comment: the link you mentioned had some resources that are worth looking into! thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

A similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44260217/hyperparameter-optimization-for-pytorch-model) was already answered in-depth it seems.

However, in short, you can use something called **Grid Search**. With Grid Search, you set the values you want to try for each hyperparameter, and then Grid Search will try every combination. This [link](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/what-is-the-best-way-to-perform-hyper-parameter-search-in-pytorch/19943/3) shows how to do it with PyTorch

The following [Medium Post](https://medium.com/pytorch/accelerate-your-hyperparameter-optimization-with-pytorchs-ecosystem-tools-bc17001b9a49) goes more in-depth about other methods and packages to try, but I think you should start with a simple grid search.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. For grid search, from what I understand, you will have to train your model on certain possible values of hyper params first right? and then run grid search to find the best model? is there a way by which we don't input the possible/guessed hyper param values & the function converges to the optimal values?